# Python restart program if reaching some statement

Tags: python

I have a python application that uses a lot of packages and during my runs I experience some memory leakage, this accumulates even though I copy and delete all my variables.

So in the end the program crashes. So I think a solution could be to restart the program when the memory becomes a problem. In order to eliminate all the garbage the old program needs to be killed to free up the memory after starting the new session.

The basic code could look like this:

```
results = load('results')
data = load('data')
results += some_stupid_operation(results,data)
save('results', results)
restart_program() # Kill current program and start new instance
```

It is okay if it is in Ipython.

Disclaimer: I know this generally not a solution for memory leakage. Putting the operations in functions should solve the problem. Since the garbage collector then should fix it by itself as dabadaba commented.

Solution given by Rossi Milan Bob. Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# program testing the solution
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    sys.argv=[sys.argv[0],'1']
else:
    sys.argv[1]=str(int(sys.argv[1])+1) # increment iteration
print sys.argv
a=np.zeros(10**6) # approximate 10 MB
# Memory does not accumulate over iterations
# Looking at system monitor
if int(sys.argv[1])<100:
    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

Comment: If you put your logic in a function and you exit from that function, that should be enough to free up the memory.

Comment: The solution is almost certainly to *not* "copy and delete all my variables".

Comment: I completly agree with dabadaba. This should not be nesserary nor desirable, but my programs crashes. 
The "copy-delete" logic was "pythons garbage collector can't delete some data from the stupid operation."  There must be some links I'm not aware of. Copy.deepcopy eleminates all links to the original object if I understod it correct. So after a deletion all old objects should be dereferenced completly. You know you try stuff to exclude posibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to restart the script if you're running the script like following `$ python yourpgm.py`

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

If you're running the script like `$ chmod a+x yourpgm.py` and `$ ./yourpgm.py` use the following code to restart the program.

```
os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

Either way, do not forget to import the sys module:

```
import sys
```

Make sure you made the script executable by adding the following code on the top of the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Solution added to the question.