# How do you use a tkinter button to make restart the python program?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

im new to python. im try to make restart button tkinter for my python gui program. Im still confused how to do it. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is it the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019034/how-to-make-restart-python-program-button-using-tkinter-button)?

Comment: @acw1668 I bet it's the same person on a different account because they didn't get an answer to the question they posted earlier. The question is the same, and the writing style is similar. @ DoniFidomen I suggest you edit your question with a [mre], otherwise people can't really help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python restart program if reaching some statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063918/python-restart-program-if-reaching-some-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the code that starts the GUI into a function (main) and setting the button command to another function (restart) that destroys the window and calls the main function. Don't forget to call the main function at the bottom of the file. It would look something like this:

```py
import tkinter

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Restart", command=lambda: restart(root))
    # All the other buttons, labels, etc
    tkinter.mainloop()

def restart(window):
    window.destroy()
    main()

main()
```

Comment: This wouldn't exactly work if there are socket/files opened or other global variables that need to be reset. Also what if OP has 2 `tkinter.Tk` windows open, you need to close both of them.